# Javascript operators could not compare integers with zeros (eg. 10, 100, 1000 etc)?

Tags: javascript

The javascript operators in my program could not identify integers that ends with all zeros. For example it can't identify 10, 100, 2000, 90000 etc. Which also means any number with trailing 0's can't be read. It could identify and compare `20001` and such.

Sample code:

```
if ((document.forms.frmApprovalTrainees.elements[TxtFldName].value) > 100 )
{
 alert("Please enter approved quantity less than the requested"); 
   return false;
}
```

The `(document.forms.frmApprovalTrainees.elements[TxtFldName].value)` is supposed to retrieve the input value for validation. In the case above the operator identifies the `100` as `1`. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because an input's value is a string. Use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Don't forget to use a decimal radix.

```
if (parseInt(document.forms.frmApprovalTrainees.elements[TxtFldName].value, 10) > 100)
```

The radix is there to make sure the string is parsed as a decimal number (and not octal or hexadecimal, as `FFFF` can be though of as a number as well).

Comment: With a radix, please... but why is this needed, what does this do? How does str > num (not) work? Example?

Comment: @WenJi No problem. Make sure to accept my answer if you find it correct, it will benefit both me, you, and the community :). Good luck

Comment: ya won't forget to add radix parseInt(string,radix). Thanks!

Comment: -1, since this doesn't answer the question. The [specs](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.5) say that a string get implicitly converted to a number (when compared to another number). This works in every browser.

Comment: @Truth's post did solved my problem. Javascript variables does recognize strings as numbers but i'm not sure why for this case it doesn't. Any other integer can be compared without a problem but once i start using numbers that ends with 0 it wouldn't read it.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 if what you said was really implemented properly, we wouldn't be needing praseInt now would we?

Comment: @Truth You need parseInt when comparing two strings, but not when comparing a string to a number. As pst pointed out, you should try to find a counterexample (...which you won't...). The interesting thing about the question is that the OP's implementation works in most cases, but not with trailing 0's

Comment: @Pumbaa80 is right with the trailing 0's. Is it by any chance a javascript bug?

Comment: when comparing a string and a number, it will make the number a string and do a LEXICOGRAPHIC comparison (which makes '101' greater than '1000')

Comment: @BobFincheimer No! '101' is bigger than '1000' because they are *both strings*. But `'101' < 1000` and `101 < '1000'`